# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in vueJs (AmChart Implementation)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, amcharts, vuetify.js

Good Day Master!
I'm new in programming and now i'm in progress to do a vue.js dashboard.
Currently I'm implementing amChart in VueJs to fill the dashboard, but i found a trouble of ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined*** so the value doesnt appear in chart. Code as below:

HTML:

```
    <v-container grid-list-xl fluid>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex lg8>
          <v-card> 
            <div 
              id="chartdiv" 
              style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"              
              ></div>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
```

Script:

```
data: () => ({
    transactions: []
  }),
methods: {
    getDataChart() {
      api.getTransactions(
        {},
        this.getTransactionsSuccessCallback,
        this.getTransactionsErrorCallback
      );
    },
    getTransactionsSuccessCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);

      for (let i = 0; i < response.data.items.length; i++) {
        let item = response.data.items[i];
        console.log(item);
        var dataChart = {
          transaction_date: new Date(item.transaction_date),
          debit_amount: item.debit_amount
        };

        this.transactions.push(dataChart);
      }
      console.log(this.transactions);
    },
    getTransactionsErrorCallback(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getDataChart();
  },
```

and this is my AmChart script

```
created(transactions) {
    chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
      type: "serial",
      theme: "dark",
      marginRight: 40,
      marginLeft: 40,
      autoMarginOffset: 20,
      dataDateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD",
      dataProvider: transactions,
      valueAxes: [
        {
          id: "v1",
          axisAlpha: 0,
          position: "left",
          ignoreAxisWidth: true
        }
      ],
      balloon: {
        borderThickness: 1,
        shadowAlpha: 0
      },
      graphs: [
        {
          id: "g1",
          balloon: {
            drop: true,
            adjustBorderColor: false,
            color: "#ffffff",
            type: "smoothedLine"
          },
          fillAlphas: 0.2,
          bullet: "round",
          bulletBorderAlpha: 1,
          bulletColor: "#FFFFFF",
          bulletSize: 5,
          hideBulletsCount: 50,
          lineThickness: 2,
          title: "red line",
          useLineColorForBulletBorder: true,
          valueField: "debit_amount",
          balloonText: "<span style='font-size:18px;'>[[debit_amount]]</span>"
        }
      ],
      chartCursor: {
        valueLineEnabled: true,
        valueLineBalloonEnabled: true,
        cursorAlpha: 0,
        zoomable: false,
        valueZoomable: true,
        valueLineAlpha: 0.5
      },
      valueScrollbar: {
        autoGridCount: true,
        color: "#000000",
        scrollbarHeight: 50
      },
      categoryField: "transaction_date",
      categoryAxis: {
        minPeriod: "mm",
        parseDates: true,
        dashLength: 1,
        minorGridEnabled: true
      },
      export: {
        enabled: true
      }
    });
```

Anyone can help me for this problem? Because i still noob in programming :D.
Thank You Before

Comment: What does your console.log(response) give you?

Comment: Hy Andrew, it gives me array object of my data

Comment: Ok, and is 'items' an element in that array and is it an array also?

Comment: Yes Andrew,  correct,  'items'  is an element in that array and it is also an array.

Comment: The error you're getting must be from this line `for (let i = 0; i < response.data.items.length; i++) {` so although you have 'items' in your response maybe you don't need the 'data'. Not sure. Maybe edit your question and include the full console log of response and we can probably see how that line should be written.